# Show the coercivity of a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, bilinear-form

I have the following bilinear form $B:L^{2}(I) \times L^{2}(I) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where
\begin{align}
B(u,v)= \int_{I} \alpha u v dx - \int_{I} \left( \int_{x}^{x_{max}} \beta(x,y) \alpha(y) u(y)  dy \right) v(x) dx ,
\end{align}
where $I=[0,x_{max}]$, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive functions.

I want to show that $B$ is coercive (to show well posedness of a related problem), which means that $\exists c>0$ such that
\begin{align}
B(v,v) \geq c \| v \|_{L^{2}(I)}.
\end{align}
Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, unless more conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are specified. Take $\alpha$, $\beta$ constant, $x_\max=1$, and take $u=1$:
$$
B(u,u) = \alpha - \int_I \beta\alpha (1-x) \ dx = \alpha (1-\beta/2).
$$
Hence $B$ is not coercive if $\beta=2$ and $\alpha>0$ constant.

Comment: I agree. But let me make it clearer. I do not want to show this for all $ \alpha$ and $\beta$. I want to see what kind of functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$, that satisfies the above conditions, can give the desired result.